# Datetimes in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, datetime, time

Im not particularly skilled when it comes to working with datetimes in js. I have a JSON object that has some datetime fields formatted like `YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS` now I have to put this in `HH:mm AM/PM` and I came up with:

```
var d = Date.parse('2013-04-17T13:05:00');
var date = new Date(d);
var hrs = date.getUTCHours();
var min = date.getUTCMinutes();
var meridian;
if(hrs > 12){
    hrs -= 12;
    meridian = 'PM';
}
else {
    meridian = 'AM';
}
if (min < 10) {
    min = "0"+min;
};
var time = hrs+":"+min+" "+meridian;
```

Is there a better way to accomplish this?

Comment: nope. that's about it. the JS datetime object has essentially NO output formatting capabilities built into it.

Comment: There is a `.toLocaleFormat` method, but alas, it only works in Firefox. You'd need to use a library if you want something easier, but unless you need to juggle timezones it's usually more efficient to just write your own formatter for your particular case.

Comment: The better way is to use a well tested date library. Moment.js is a good place to start.

Comment: ISO date parsing is not available in every JS environment.  [See here](http://dygraphs.com/date-formats.html).  Use moment.js.  It works everywhere.

Comment: @MattJohnson I just realized that :( honestly I wanted to stay away from having to add another library as the app has a lot already

Comment: A developer in my team wrote his own date algorithm instead of using .Net's build-in date functions to add and subtract dates... He's not working with us anymore. Just use moment.js and mark that answer as correct if it was useful to you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

try moment.js, this library has a ton of functionality built in.

http://momentjs.com/

```
moment(String, String);
moment("12-25-1995", "MM-DD-YYYY");
```

"hA" is the righ format for "3PM" format

Comment: Any time someone is using date times with Javascript, I recommend moment.js. It makes lives better.

Comment: Yes and its pretty easy to use, but also offers a lot of functionality

Answer (score 0):

A different answer for a different approach

> has some datetime fields formatted like `YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS` now I have to put this in `HH:mm AM/PM`

As you **know the formatting**, you can take the parts you want directly from the datetime *String*, avoiding the use of a *Date* instance or library all together.

```
var stamp = '2013-04-17T13:05:00',
    hrs = +stamp.slice(11, 13), // 13
    min = +stamp.slice(14, 16); //  5
```

then continue as before from here.

Answer (score -1):

This is overkill, but I recently went out of my way to make my own *function* just for things like this

```
var easyDate = (function () {
    var days = ['Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday'],
        months = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December'],
        thstndrd = ['th', 'st', 'nd', 'rd', 'th', 'th', 'th', 'th', 'th', 'th'],
        toDate = function () {return new Date(Date.UTC(this.yyyy, this.MM - 1, this.dd, this.hh, this.mm, this.ss, this.ms));},
        toLocaleDate = function () {return new Date(this.yyyy, this.MM - 1, this.dd, this.hh, this.mm, this.ss, this.ms);},
        UTC = function UTC(d) {
            return {
                ms: d.getUTCMilliseconds(),
                ss: d.getUTCSeconds(),
                mm: d.getUTCMinutes(),
                hh: d.getUTCHours(),
                dd: d.getUTCDate(),
                MM: d.getUTCMonth() + 1,
                yyyy: d.getUTCFullYear(),
                dow: d.getUTCDay(),
                toDate: toDate,
                toLocaleDate: toLocaleDate
            }
        },
        easyDate = function easyDate(d) {
            var o = UTC(d);
            return {
                dd: '' + o.dd,
                th: thstndrd[o.dd % 10],
                day: days[o.dow],
                MM: '' + o.MM,
                month: months[o.MM - 1],
                year: '' + o.yyyy,
                am: o.hh < 12 ? 'a.m.' : 'p.m.',
                hh: o.hh < 10 ? '0' + o.hh : '' + o.hh,
                h: '' + (o.hh % 12 || 12),
                mm: o.mm < 10 ? '0' + o.mm : '' + o.mm,
                ss: o.ss < 10 ? '0' + o.ss : '' + o.ss,
                ms: ('00' + o.ms).slice(-3),
                UTC: o
            };
        };
    easyDate.UTC = UTC;
    easyDate.delta = function (then, now) {
        var o, p, dir = -1;
        now || (now = new Date());
        if (now >= then) o = UTC(now), p = UTC(then);
        else o = UTC(then), p = UTC(now), now = then, dir = 1;
        o.dir = dir;
        o.dow = p.dow;
        o.ms = o.ms - p.ms;
        o.ss = o.ss - p.ss;
        o.mm = o.mm - p.mm;
        o.hh = o.hh - p.hh;
        o.dd = o.dd - p.dd;
        o.MM = o.MM - p.MM;
        o.yyyy = o.yyyy - p.yyyy;
        // fix negatives
        if (o.ms < 0) --o.ss, o.ms = (o.ms + 1000) % 1000;
        if (o.ss < 0) --o.mm, o.ss = (o.ss +   60) %   60;
        if (o.mm < 0) --o.hh, o.mm = (o.mm +   60) %   60;
        if (o.hh < 0) --o.dd, o.hh = (o.hh +   24) %   24;
        if (o.dd < 0) { // months have different lengths
            --o.MM;
            now.setUTCMonth(now.getUTCMonth() + 1);
            now.setUTCDate(0);
            o.dd = (o.dd + now.getUTCDate()) % now.getUTCDate();
        }
        if (o.MM < 0)  --o.yyyy, o.MM = (o.MM + 12) % 12;
        return o;
    };
    return easyDate;
}());
```

And using it

```
var o = easyDate(new Date());
o.month + ' ' + o.dd + o.th + ', ' + o.h + ':' + o.mm + ' ' + o.am;
// "June 18th, 7:30 p.m."
```

If you noticed the thing called `easyDate.delta` in the code, yep, it supports calculating differences in time, too. If you just want to run `getUTC*` for everything then you have `easyDate.UTC`. :)

Comment: If you're wondering why I did it when there is _moment.js_, I like to know exactly what is happening, why, and only have what I need (I like _Objects_ more than _Strings_). This also minifies down to 1.4 kb with closure compiler (a quarter the size of _moment_).

Comment: The OP asked about parsing an ISO8601 formatted string. Your code doesn't do that at all.

Comment: I understood the question `Is there a better way to accomplish this?` to be about formatting _Date_ (or skipping _Date_ entirely), not about how to convert _ISO 8601_ to _Date_.

Comment: Umm... not sure how you missed it, he said quite clearly: "I have a JSON object that has some datetime fields formatted like YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS"

Comment: @MattJohnson He also gets from `YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS` to a _Date_ without error in 2 lines. Yes, it could be done in one with just a `new Date('2013-04-17T13:05:00');`, but he's demonstrated that he is able to parse it.